# How to restore/rewind my PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, restore, database-restore, pg-restore

We do nightly full backups of our db and I then use that dump to create my own dev-db. The creation of the dev-db takes roughly 10 minutes so its scheduled every morning by cron before I get to work. So I can now work with an *almost* live db.

But when I'm testing things it would sometimes be convenient to rollback the full db or just some specific tables to the initial backup. Of course I could do the full recreation of the dev-db but that would make me wait for another 10 minutes before I could run the tests again.

**So is there an easy way to restore/rewind the database/table to a specific point in time or from a dump?**

I have tried to use `pg_restore` like this to restore specific tables:

```
pg_restore -d my-dev-db -n stuff -t tableA -t tableB latest-live-db.dump
```

I have tried with options like `-c`and `--data-only` also. But there seems to be several issues here that I did not foresee:

- The old data is not automatically removed when the restored data is *copied* back.
- There is several foreign-key constraints that makes this impossible (correct me if I'm wrong) without explicitly removing the FK before the restore and then adding them back again.
- PK-sequences that gets out of order does not concern me at all at this point but that might be an issue as well.

---

*Edit: more things I tested/looked into:*

- [`pg_basebackup`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-pgbasebackup.html)
- A more brute force alternative to `pg_basebackup` is to stop the db-server, copy the db-files, then start the db-server.

Both of the alternatives above fail because I have several local databases running in the same cluster and that sums up to a lot of data on disk. There is no way to separate the databases this way! So the file copy action here will not give me any speed gain.

Comment: Might this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/876522/creating-a-copy-of-a-database-in-postgres It asks about pgAdmin but since the command is regular SQL, it should be enough. Use your dev-database as template and create a new one from it every time you need it.

Comment: PITR and WAL archiving?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are asking about a database not a cluster. The first thing that comes to my mind is to restore the backup to 2 different dbs, one with the `dev_db` name and the other with another name like `dev_db_back`. Then when you need a fresh db drop `dev_db` and rename `dev_db_backup` to `dev_db` with

```
drop database if exists dev_db;
alter database dev_db_backup rename to dev_db;
```

After that, to have another source to rename from, restore the backup to `dev_db_backup` again. This could be done by a script so the dropping, renaming and restoring would be automated. As dropping and renaming are instantaneous just start the script and the renaming is done without a need to wait for the new restore.

If it is common to need repeated restores in less 10 minutes intervals I think you can try to do what you are doing inside a transaction:

```
begin;
-- alter the db
-- test the alterations
commit; -- or ...
-- rollback;
```

Comment: This is a good suggestion that sort of takes me closer to where I want to be. There is still the limitation that I have only one hot backup to use, then its the 10 minute wait again to get a fresh backup. I will probably use something like this though!

Comment: @UlfR It looks like you need transactions. Updated