# Copying postgresql data without roles

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I have a snapshot of a Postgres database named **srcDB** in a file named **srcDB-cachedump.gz**, obtained using pg_dump.  The dump is from a production database, so there are a bunch of different roles.  What I would like to do is make a development database called **devDB**, which has only one role, a user by the name of 'development', but with the same schema as the original database.

The way I initially tried to do this was:

```
gunzip -c srcDB-cachedump.gz | psql -d devDB -U development -W
```

When I ran this, however, I got many errors that boiled down to, essentially, "role  does not exist."  I would like to bypass the recreation of the roles in the production database if at all possible, as I have other programmers on my team and I would like the dev environment to be as portable as possible. I am relatively new at Postgres administration, though, so I am at a loss.

Comment: You may want to use `pg_restore` instead of `psql` to restore your DB. It has a set of options you may need. You may also need to change DB dump format form `sql-in-archive` to postgres custom bump format.

Comment: Here are the links to manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgrestore.html http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html

Comment: You can visit below link to get your answer

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/876522/creating-a-copy-of-a-database-in-postgres/27062545#27062545

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko, the problem is that I am working with a dump file (plain text) in a particular format and I do not have access to the original database.

Comment: @rogue_js You can still try to use `pg_restore` with plain text dump. I am not shure it will work.

Comment: It doesn't :(.  The trick ended up being using a couple of different options when storing to the text format (I had to call my admin late to make it happen).  If anyone else has this problem in the future and needs plaintext format you can run pg_dump with the flags "--no-owner and --no-privileges."