# How to clone development-mode database to production-mode datatable with database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I imported millions of record into the database `devise_with_ldap_development`

I wonder how to clone the data into another database `devise_with_ldap_production` for production mode rather than re-do the import rake task Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/876522/creating-a-copy-of-a-database-in-postgres

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend another solution which does not appear in the comment link above.

That is using [*pg_dump*](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html) in conjunction with the `-Fc` switch, which is a custom binary format which is much more compact than an SQL dump. This can then be applied via [*pg_restore*](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgrestore.html) to a blank db created by *createdb*.

As an added benefit over the pure *createdb*/`CREATE DATABASE` methods, this will also leave a backup behind which you can store somewhere, and have on hand should you need to restore that same dump again, whether to the same DB after it's been dropped, or a new copy.