# Is there a way to use 'COPY' command(PostgreSQL) in windows cli?

Tags: postgresql

Trying to use 'copy' command of PostgreSQL in windows cli command:

```
COPY myTable FROM value.txt (DELIMITER('|'));
```

I can't find 'copy' executable file in bin directory.

Can you let me know how can I run 'copy' command in cli?

Added:
My windows application is going to use the 'Copy' feature.
Need to run it directly from Application.

Thanks in advance.

I could manage to see my required result with following approach.

```
psql.exe -f copy.sql -p 5433 -U user -s postgres

copy.sql
\copy TARGET_TABLE FROM source.txt (DELIMITER('#'));
```

Comment: Might [this SO article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/876522/creating-a-copy-of-a-database-in-postgresql) be of use to you?

Comment: It seems that it is for backing up all database? I just need to upload the text file into a table frequently. Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking to _copy_ an entire table, or to _INSERT_ into a table from a source text file?

Comment: There are several lines text in the source text file, and I want to upload those ones into the table. Looks like INSERT. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using any GUI like PgAdmin ?

Comment: Which programming language are you using? In JDBC you can use the `CopyManager` API: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/copy/CopyManager.html which can be used to insert a file which is located on the _client_ side. `copy` requires the file to be on the _server_ (where Postgres is running).

Comment: Thank you but I don't use JDBC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the right command (`COPY`), but you need to begin an interactive session with Postgres if you want use the `COPY` command from the Windows command line.

```
psql -U username yourdb
```

This should leave you at a prompt looking like the following:

```
yourdb=#
```

Now you can use the `COPY` command and it should work:

```
COPY myTable FROM value.txt (DELIMITER('|'))
```

The problem you were having is that `COPY` is not a Windows executable program, it is a Postgres command which is only understood by Postgres.

Comment: I see. My windows application should use 'copy' feature directly, so I wonder if I can upload text file content without put 'COPY' command in the prompt.

Comment: You might be able to write a batch script which will begin the Postgres session behind the scenes.  The input could be the `COPY` query you want to run.

Comment: I just used a "-f" option to access copy.sql.

Answer (score 0):

For loading Json use the below command- 
\COPY myTable (data) FROM '~specifypath/data.json';

data is the column where you want to push the json