# Copy Postgres database structures but not data

Tags: database, postgresql, docker

We are creating a Dockerfile that can spin up a Postgres database container, using this image as a basis

https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/

Every time we test we want to create a fresh database with the production database as a template - we want to copy the database structures without copying the data in tables etc.

Can someone provide an example of doing this? I need something concrete with database urls etc.

There are some good examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876522/creating-a-copy-of-a-database-in-postgresql), but some are a bit nebulous to a Postgres newb.

I see examples like this:

```
pg_dump production-db | psql test-db
```

I don't know what "production-db" / "test-db" refer to (are they URL strings?), so I am lost. Also, I believe this copies over all the data in the DB, and we really just want to copy the database structures (tables, views, etc).

Comment: Probably the intended command was `pg_dump prod-db | psql local-db` which means: run pg_dump on prod-db and pipe the output into test-db. For *only the structures* you possibly mean `pg_dump --schema-only ...`. See the manual or `pg_dump --help` for usage hints. NB: `prod-db` and `test-db` are the names of the old and new databases.

Comment: thanks! --schema-only might be useful info!

Comment: but do you know what "prod-db" and "local-db" are? are they URLs?

Comment: Well, it could be *metasyntactic* names; just substitute them by your *actual* database names.

Comment: right but test-db is in a local Docker container and production-db is on a completely different server, the pointers to both will be completely different, it has to be some sort of URL string, possibly with creds in the string, I will go read the pg_dump docs, but if you have any guidance on that it would help

Comment: database names are local to the machine. But you can invoke pg_dump from a remote machine, if you use the `-h <IP-address_or_hostname_here>` flag. You probably need to specify a username, too. And a password. And URLs are useless here.

Comment: @AlexanderMills: *"it has to be some sort of URL string"* No, it doesn't. See [docs for pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/app-pgdump.html)

Comment: in my case, it does need that info, because I am dumping between two separate machines