# How to start new Rails project with existing database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I would like to start new Rails(v 6.0) project with an existing postgresql database on local machine.

In order to move the data I used gem 'yaml_db' which dumped data from the existing db into data.yml. I created two migrations: one to load schema a second to load data from data.yml file. The second one is failing to migrate, because of foreign key constraints errors. I followed the steps in this article: https://medium.com/@kitsched/starting-a-ruby-on-rails-project-from-existing-data-7dda5044c85f

Is there some easier way to accomplish this? After I manage to load the data, can I just copy the model files from old Rails(v 4.0) application?

Thank you

Comment: I would'nt use migrations to move the data, its not at all what they are intended to do. Instead use `pg_dump` and `pg_restore`.

Comment: I also don't see the point in using yaml_db unless you are changing from something else than postgres. The PG tools are superior and do dumps as SQL instead of dumping SQL to another format only to convert it back which is really ineffective.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a copy of a database in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876522/creating-a-copy-of-a-database-in-postgresql)