# How to login to postgresql db - After session kill (for copy database)

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, psql, pgadmin

I tried to copy a database within the same server using postgresql server

I tried the below query

```
CREATE DATABASE newdb WITH TEMPLATE originaldb OWNER dbuser;
```

And got the below error

```
ERROR:  source database "originaldb" is being accessed by 1 other user
```

So, I executed the below command

```
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pg_stat_activity.pid) FROM pg_stat_activity 
WHERE pg_stat_activity.datname = 'originaldb' AND pid <> pg_backend_pid();
```

Now none of us are able to login/connect back to the database.

When I provide the below command

```
psql -h 192.xx.xx.x -p 9763 -d originaldb -U postgres
```

It prompts for a password and upon keying password, it doesn't return any response

May I understand why does this happen?  How can I connect to the db back? How do I restart/make the system to let us login back?

Can someone help us with this?

Comment: Best guess is killed backends you should not have. I'm guessing you will need to restart server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like something is holding an access exclusive lock on a shared catalog, such as pg_database.  If that is the case, no one will be able to log in until that lock gets released.  I wouldn't think the session-killing code you ran would cause such a situation, though.  Maybe it was just a coincidence.

If you can't find an active session, you can try using system tools to figure out what is going on, like `ps -efl|fgrep postgre`.  Or you can just restart the whole database instance, using whatever method you would usually use to do that, like `pg_ctl restart -D <data_directory>` or `sudo service postgresql restart`  or some GUI method if you are on an OS that does that.