# I want to maintain a copy of the prod DB for analytics Rails 5.2.5 postgresql

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5, redash

I'm working on a Rails 5 app with postgres db. I want to expose the data to https://redash.io/ for reposting and data visualization but for safety reasons I don't want to directly expose the production db.

I'm thinking about trying to create/maintain a copy of the prod db and have redash read from that instead - reducing the risk to the prod db.

The copy db wouldn't need to be updated in real time - I'd like it to copy from the prod db maybe once per day.

My initial thoughts were to have a script that creates a replica db using prod as the template like this; [Creating a copy of a database in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876522/creating-a-copy-of-a-database-in-postgresql)
The problem I see with that approach is that it would need to terminate any existing connections while copying and we have users accessing the app 24hrs per day.

Perhaps more plausible would be to create a new db for the rails app using the prod db as a template and then schedule the data to be copied from one to the other. This way I could leverage future migrations to keep the fields/tables in sync between the two as the db grows/changes.

Am I on the right track? Is there a smarter way of achieving this? Is there a way of using redash to safely query a production db (no accidental write actions, sensitive data masking, etc?)?

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options:

I think there are a number of options depending on your architecture requirements:

- Use a read replica - this adds additional overhead and costs to you infra however does separate the workload from your prod origin so there will be no impact of users execute long running queries. If Redash needs to write data then this eliminates this option.
- Polyscale.ai - PolyScale is an intelligent database cache that plugs in to your database and scales the reads to different locations. This would mean that your Redash access is external and the queries run against PolyScale, with cache misses reading from the origin database. You may want to setup some manual cache rules e.g. cache all data for an hour or similar. They support table based rules which would work well. Cached queries would be very fast.
- CDC stream - use a tool like Debezium or AWS DMS to generate a change data capture stream and push the data to another database.

Hope that helps.